# PHP: Why is my variable always true, never false?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, working on a school assignment.  I am simply trying to set a boolean variable using a function.  Yet with the following code:

```
$alreadyExists = idExists($id);

if($alreadyExists) {
    print 'value was true';
} else {
    print 'value was false';
}

...other code...

function idExists($id)
{
    return false;
}
```

It ALWAYS prints "the value was true".  I have tried making the function "return true", "return false", my actual function code, etc.  The variable is always set to true, no matter what my function says.  Why?

Thanks!

Comment: @JayBlanchard But it returned `false` - shouldn't it be false?

Comment: The above syntax would work fine regardless of where the function is defined, this is php... I would suggest something else is going on with your code as the above code works as expected for me.

Comment: Your code works just fine: https://3v4l.org/koUdr. Something else is wrong with your code, that you aren't showing here.

Comment: The problem looks to be in `...other code...`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen that's *always* where the problem is ;)

Comment: outdated books? 70 yr. old teachers? who knows.

Comment: That could not be true!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `$id` and not the boolean `true|false`. Your conditional statement will take care of that, and return whether the value is true or false, as you already have it in the prints.

```
$id = 1; // wherever that's coming from.

$alreadyExists = idExists($id);

if($alreadyExists) {
    print 'value was true';
} else {
    print 'value was false';
}

// ...other code...

function idExists($id)
{

   return $id;

}
```

- Your checking on true/false in the return will always be just that.
- If `$id` were non-existant, it will return as false.

---

Having the following commented `$id` will return false.

```
// $id = 1;

$alreadyExists = idExists($id);

if($alreadyExists) {
    print 'value was true';
} else {
    print 'value was false';
}

// ...other code...

function idExists($id)
{

   return $id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is this function

```
function idExists($id)
{
    return false;
}
```

No matter what the value of `$id` this function returns false, so why pass in the variable `$id` at all?

Other things that even if you fixed this function might cause problems are

You see in this code, right here,

```
$alreadyExists = idExists($id);
```

the function `idExists()` is executed immediately when its read (i.e first line so read first executed first `$idExists` executed once with god knows what `$id` value), Now the variable `$alreadyExists` is set (**SET!!**),  just because you have assigned that variable to the return value of the function `idExists()` doesn't mean that by acccesing `$alreadyExists` the `$idExists()` function is magically executed.no matter how many times you access `$alreadyExists` the value of it remains same unless modified by assignment operator or something else.

SO unless this code exists in a function that gets called with updated values of `$id` your `$alreadyExists` variable value will be unchanged.

```
$alreadyExists = idExists($id);

if($alreadyExists) {
    print 'value was true';
} else {
    print 'value was false';
}
```

I'd actually modify this to look like this since you are using $alreadyExists only once in this scope

```
if(idExists($id)) {
    print 'value was true';
} else {
    print 'value was false';
}
```